# Why is the positional parameter still present after sourcing the script?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, positional-parameter

I am sourcing a script and the value of the positional parameter is reflecting even after the script is sourced.

```
$ echo $1

$ . $SCRIPTS_DIR/xeye.sh ryadqa
Done
$ echo $1
ryadqa
```

Comment: Why should it disappear just because you sourced a script...? This is completely expected behaviour afaik

Comment: This is not the case in other environments. Positional parameter is relative to the script. I am not sure, if this is expected.

Comment: @summithere : You tagged your question *bash* and *ksh*. You should make clear, whether you want an answer for bash or for ksh.

Answer (score 0):

As for bash, this is from the bash man-page, which explains the `source` command:

*source filename [arguments] ... If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is  executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.*

(Note that positional parameters refers to that of the sourcing script, because sourcing of a file occurs in the context of the sourcing script).